# How to properly start and shut down a local multi-node network？

Tags: deploy

Following the tutorial on this website(https://docs.solanalabs.com/cluster/bench-tps), I successfully start local multinode testnet.I discovered that I used the script `./multinode-demo/validator-x.sh` to start another node. 
Now, my question is, if I need to start more nodes, do I just need to run the `./multinode-demo/validator-x.sh` script multiple times? And if I want to restart a node, is it sufficient to kill the original node process, and then use `./multinode-demo/validator.sh` with the same **'x'** to start the node again?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've understood it correctly.

The `x` passed to `validator.sh` defines the label on the ledger directory associated with that node, which contains their local view of the network along with required identity, node, and vote account private keys.

Passing in a new `x` will create a new ledger for that validator and also spin up a new process.

And as long as you don't delete the ledger directory associated with node `x`, the script will pick back up their whole ledger and configuration when you pass in `x` once again.

Comment: Thank for your help! This has made things clearer for me